# getitem is returning null in localStorage

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to set and get item in localStorage.
and I have functional state, so I tried to get and set item as a state's key,
setitem is working but when i refresh my website localstorage is returning null.

my code is like this :

```js
  const [chart, setChart] = useState([
    empty,
    empty,
    empty,
    empty,
    empty,
    empty,
    empty,
    empty,
  ]);
  const charts = index => chart[index].key;

  const chartStorageKey = [
    charts(0),
    charts(1),
    charts(2),
    charts(3),
    charts(4),
    charts(5),
    charts(6),
    charts(7),
  ];
  
   useEffect(() => {
    const persistChart = localStorage.getItem("chart");
    JSON.parse(persistChart);
  });

  
  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("chart", JSON.stringify(chartStorageKey), [
      chartStorageKey,
    ]);
  });
```

Comment: What is `empty` is it an object that has `key`  key? Created [playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-glade-krbto?file=/src/App.js:140-180). The only thing I changed is `empty` to `{key: 'empty'}`

Comment: Thank you sir !  empty is a component that has no key

Comment: So that is an issue. Just create object `{key: empty}` that has `key` and value is `empty component`, as you are using it to map it `const charts = index => chart[index].key;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As empty is component you need to add object in this array with key key and value empty component.

```js
 const [chart, setChart] = useState([
    {key: empty},
    {key: empty},
    {key: empty},
    {key: empty},
    {key: empty},
    {key: empty},
    {key: empty},
    {key: empty},
  ]);
```

As here you are going throw array and getting key which is null in this case.

```
const charts = index => chart[index].key;
```

Here is the link to the [playground](https://codesandbox.io/s/nice-glade-krbto?file=/src/App.js:140-180)

Answer (score 1):

The useEffect sequence is wrong.

the 2nd useEffect should be at the first.

Comment: Thank you Sir , I changed as you said however, it still has same result

Answer (score 1):

UseEffect will be called in every render so add a second argument so that it will be called only when the component is mounted

```
  const [chart, setChart] = useState([
    empty,
    empty,
    empty,
    empty,
    empty,
    empty,
    empty,
    empty,
  ]);
  const charts = index => chart[index].key;

  const chartStorageKey = [
    charts(0),
    charts(1),
    charts(2),
    charts(3),
    charts(4),
    charts(5),
    charts(6),
    charts(7),
  ];

 useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("chart", JSON.stringify(chartStorageKey));
  },[]);
  
 useEffect(() => {
    const persistChart = localStorage.getItem("chart");
    console.log(persistChart)
  }, []);
```

if you want to change the local storage every time `chart` state changes then simply pass chart to the dependency array of useEffect

```
 useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem("chart", JSON.stringify(chartStorageKey));
  },[chart]);
  
 useEffect(() => {
    const persistChart = localStorage.getItem("chart");
    console.log(persistChart)
  }, [chart]);
```

Answer (score 1):

Pass an empty array as a second argument in the first useEffect

```
useEffect(() => {
  const persistChart = localStorage.getItem("chart");
  JSON.parse(persistChart);
}, []);
```

In the second useEffect `[chartStorageKey]` should be an argument in `useEffect`, not in `setItem`

```
useEffect(() => {
  localStorage.setItem("chart", JSON.stringify(chartStorageKey));
}, [chartStorageKey]);
```